# Panda's info() to HTML

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas offers some summary statistics with the `describe()` function called on a `DataFrame`. The output of the function is another `DataFrame`, so it's easily exported to HTML with a call to `to_html()`.

It also offers information about the `DataFrame` with the `info()` function, but that's printed out, returning `None`. Is there a way to get the same information as a `DataFrame` or any other way that can be exported to HTML?

Here is a sample `info()` for reference:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 7 columns):
0    5 non-null float64
1    5 non-null float64
2    5 non-null float64
3    5 non-null float64
4    5 non-null float64
5    5 non-null float64
6    5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(7)
memory usage: 360.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With input from all these great answers, I ended up doing the following:

- Strip the first three and last two lines away, because they contain memory information and other things that are not in tabular format (and a fixed number of lines)
- Convert the column information  (`datatype` in the snippet below) into a pandas' DataFrame using `StringIO`
- Renamed the columns "count", "null" and "dtype"
- Returned the html of the column info and the plain text of the remaining lined (first 3 and last 2)

So there result is this:

```
def process_content_info(content: pd.DataFrame):
    content_info = StringIO()
    content.info(buf=content_info)
    str_ = content_info.getvalue()

    lines = str_.split("\n")
    table = StringIO("\n".join(lines[3:-3]))
    datatypes = pd.read_table(table, delim_whitespace=True, 
                   names=["column", "count", "null", "dtype"])
    datatypes.set_index("column", inplace=True)

    info = "\n".join(lines[0:2] + lines[-2:-1])

    return info, datatypes
```

Perhaps the second StringIO can be simplified, but anyway this achieves what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

A solution can be to save the output of info() to a writable buffer (using the [buf](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) argument) and then [converting to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715027/converting-text-file-to-html-file-with-python).

Below an example using a txt file as buffer, but this could be easily done in memory using `StringIO`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns =['A', 'B', 'C'])

_ = frame.info(buf = open('test_pandas.txt', 'w'))   #save to txt

# Example to convert to html
contents = open("test_pandas.txt","r")
with open("test_pandas.html", "w") as e:
    for lines in contents.readlines():
        e.write("<pre>" + lines + "</pre> <br>\n")
```

Here's how the txt looks like:

[image]

The variation using StringIO can be found in @jezrael answer, so probably no point updating this answer.

Comment: I tried the buf option the first thing but didn't work for me. Does your txt contain any text?

Comment: yes it does. did you specify 'w' option?
I tested the example above and it works producing both a txt and html

Comment: I copied the exact code you have typed and i am not able to reproduce your output. What's your python and pandas version?

Comment: I have Python 2.7 and pandas 0.18.1

Comment: Thanks. This can all be done in memory with ``StringIO`` as well.

Comment: Yes , but can you confirm that it works ? I tried a buffer1 = StringIO() and tried giving that as the buf parameter , for some reason when i try to print my buffer i get a None

Comment: Aah, i used StringIO instead of BytesIO on 2.7 python , that was the problem, anyway ,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I try rewrite another solution with `StringIO`, also is necessary use `getvalue()` with `split`:

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO

frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns =['A', 'B', 'C'])

a = StringIO()
frame.info(buf = a)  

# Example to convert to html
contents = a.getvalue().split('\n')
with open("test_pandas.html", "w") as e:
    for lines in contents:
        e.write("<pre>" + lines + "</pre> <br>\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import StringIO
output = StringIO.StringIO()
#Write df.info to a string buffer
df.info(buf=output)
#put the info back to a dataframe so you can use df.to_html()
df_info =  pd.DataFrame(columns=['DF INFO'], data=output.getvalue().split('\n'))
df_info.to_html()
```