ipynb HTML Output displaying tabs using ipywidgets
Being used to working with R Markdown I tried finding a solution for tabbing charts/ results to create a cleaner output. In R this is simple by adding {.tabset} to a parent section all subsequent child sections are tabbed.
R Notebook Tabs
However, there seems to be no such straightforward solution with jupyter notebooks. My current method is using ipywidgets. The code bellow is displaying statistics for a list of attributes from a data table, I want to display each in a separate tab (see following image for visual).
import ipywidgets as widgets

def summary_display(df):

    out = widgets.Output()
    with out:
        print('\nStatistical Description\n')
        display(df.describe())
    return out

tab_nest = widgets.Tab()
tab_nest.children = [summary_display(data[list_of_asymmetric_binary]), 
                     summary_display(data[list_of_numeric])]
tab_nest.set_title(0, 'x')
tab_nest.set_title(1, 'list_of_numeric')

display(tab_nest)

Anaconda Jupyer Environment
When running my code through the jupyter anaconda web environment the output works. However, for an assignment we have to hand in an HTML document. When I export my code to HTML it doesn't render the tabs as shown in the screen shot, it displays the following... Tab(children=(Output(), Output()), selected_index=0, titles=('list_of_asymmetric_binary', 'list_of_numeric'))
I refuse to believe it's this complicated to implement tabbing when in R all that is required is {.tabset}. Thanks in advance for the responses.
I have tried using jupyter-nbconvert/ nbconvert instead of the jupyter anaconda web environment to export to HTML. Furthermore, I installed voila this however, opens a local host and displays the HTML document there, trying to export this doesn't work.

Did you try reading through 'Embedding Jupyter Widgets in Other Contexts than the Notebook'? It says, "The classic notebook interface provides a Widgets menu for generating an HTML snippet that can be embedded into any static web page:". And "The ipywidgets.embed module provides several functions for embedding widgets into HTML documents programmatically."

And note that Tab(children=(Output(), Output()), selected_index=0, titles=('list_of_asymmetric_binary', 'list_of_numeric')) is what you see when you aren't rendering the widget(s). If you can point to HTML on the web, you can use JupyterLite. (I'm going to assume you have to hand in actual an HTML code file for my example since that is what you say; however, others ending up here given the title, may not have that restriction.)You can JupyterLite with  ipywidgets that gets served as static content on web because the Python backing the widgets runs in browser using web assembly (WASM).

By the way, if you toggle on 'Settings' > 'Save Widget State Automatically', you'll see the HTML for the summaries saved in the code even though the tab widgets aren't rendered (not even in nbviewer), see  the additional code in the last save here where first I saved it without the state being saved. By default for now, the ipywidgets widgets need an active kernel to render and so nbviewer doesn't render them.

 Not all widgets are like that. If you scroll down here, you'll see that nbviewer can render an animation player widget that Matplotlib provides. Similar other javascript-based things like plotly will also work and be interactive in nbviewer, see here for an example. Note that isn't the case in github's preview: ...

 corresponding Jupyter notebook with Plotly example as GitHub renders it.

Making HTML page with ipywidgets-based tabs: THE BASICS
This adapts approach described on 'Embedding Jupyter Widgets in Other Contexts than the Notebook'.
Specifically using embed_minimal_html, described here, you'd run code like this:
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html

def summary_display(df):

    out = widgets.Output()
    with out:
        print('\nStatistical Description\n')
        display(df.describe())
    return out

tab_nest = widgets.Tab()
#tab_nest.children = 
#[summary_display(data[list_of_asymmetric_binary]), 
#                    summary_display(data[list_of_numeric])]

# OP didn't supply MRE so using tab widget code from https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#tabs as content for tabs
tab_contents = ['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']
children = [widgets.Text(description=name) for name in tab_contents[:2]]
tab_nest.children = children

tab_nest.set_title(0, 'x')
tab_nest.set_title(1, 'list_of_numeric')

embed_minimal_html('export.html', views=[tab_nest], title='Widgets export')

I ran this code in a Jupyter notebook with an ipykernel and the produced HTML file opened in Chrome with two tabs with content.
In lieu of a complete minimal reproducible example/self-contained code, which was not provided, I began with adapting the tabs example from ipywidgets to make the tab.children for the demo.

Update:
While above addresses the basics, the OP's code is using display of an output widget to send essentially a dataframe summary. It turns out that output doesn't pass into the content of the tabs automatically when using embed_minimal_html(), it seems. So I'm adding a version to try and use actual dataframes to have the summaries of them show in the HTML.
First question was whether HTML content in the tab widgets gets saved in the HTML produced when using embed_minimal_html()? (I didn't yet explore if embed_data has more abilities and maybe doesn't need the step to make HTML.) Demo testing that question:
#### THIS SHOWED HTML PUT IN TAB WIDGETS SHOWS UP IN PRODUCED HTML
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html

tab_nest = widgets.Tab()
#tab_nest.children = [summary_display(data), summary_display(data2)]
a = widgets.HTML(
    value="Hello <b>World</b>",
    placeholder='Some HTML',
    description='Some HTML',
)
b = widgets.HTML(
    value="Hello <b>World</b>",
    placeholder='Some more HTML',
    description='Some HTML',
)
tab_nest.children = [a, b]

tab_nest.set_title(0, 'x')
tab_nest.set_title(1, 'list_of_numeric')

embed_minimal_html('export.html', views=[tab_nest], title='HTML Export DEMO')

So it turns out that HTML content in the tab widgets indeed shows up in the HTML produced by embed_minimal_html(). Can we use that to get the dataframe summaries to be in the exported in the embeddable code?
Full demo with dataframe summaries showing in final HTML
Since HTML content of tabs gets saved by embed_minimal_html(), convert the dataframe summary to HTML from describe, (see here (and style it using the styler since it will look better in end and Pandaas styler can output HTML, too.), like so:
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html

# ----------- EXTRA TO MAKE MRE-------------------------------------------
# OP didn't supply MRE so make two dataframes 
from random import choices 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
books = ["Book_1","Book_2","Book_3","Book_4","Book_5"]
counterparties = ["Counterparty_1","Counterparty_2","Counterparty_3","Counterparty_4","Counterparty_5"]

book = choices(books, k = 100)
counterparty = choices(counterparties, k = 100)

date1, date2 = date(2018, 8, 1), date(2023, 8, 3)
res_dates = [date1]
  
while date1 != date2:
    date1 += timedelta(days=1)
    res_dates.append(date1)
  
ldd = choices(res_dates, k=100)
dict = {'book': book, 'counterparty': counterparty, 'last_trading_date': ldd} 

data = pd.DataFrame(dict)
data['last_trading_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['last_trading_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4)) # from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html
# -----------END OF EXTRA TO MAKE MRE---------------------------------------

def make_summary_display_html(df):
    #return df.describe().to_html() # based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/43976830/8508004
    return df.describe().style.background_gradient().to_html() # based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/43976830/8508004 and https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image


tab_nest = widgets.Tab()
#tab_nest.children = [summary_display(data), summary_display(data2)]
a = widgets.HTML(
    value='\n<H4>Statistical Description</H4>\n' + make_summary_display_html(data),
)
b = widgets.HTML(
    value='\n<H4>Statistical Description</H4>\n' + make_summary_display_html(data2),
)
tab_nest.children = [b, a]

tab_nest.set_title(0, 'x')
tab_nest.set_title(1, 'list_of_numeric')

#display(tab_nest) #uncomment this line to see how it looks in Jupyter
embed_minimal_html('export.html', views=[tab_nest], title='Data Summary Export')

Image of HTML Result viewed in a browser:

Image of Tabs in Jupyter without embedding (for compare and contrast):


Thank you for your response. I appreciate your effort

Thanks for everyones response, I was able to solve it by restarting the kernel and running all cells again. Subsequently going to Widgets > Save Notebook Widget State. And lastly saving the notebook to HTML.
